# Very slow file copy speed (disk to disk)

Tags: 10.10, kubuntu

I have AMD athlon x2 3gb RAM ddr2 two hdd one 80gb other 1tb
In this computer I got only ubuntu all disk in EXT4
I want to copy 10gb many file of 700mb or 1gb ( many linux ISO )

The transfer is 1mb/s this is SOOO SLOW!

I did a touch /forcefsck just in case but nothing happen it is still slow!
What might be the problem?

Comment: What is the model of your 1TB drive? Is it one of those new 4Kb-sector ones, such as WD EADS/EARS series? In this case it can be a case of mis-aligned partition - though 1Mb/sec is a bit too slow even for that

Comment: Are you still being affected by this issue? I will flag this as abandoned since it has no activity or known good answers, if you feel this issue is still affecting you and that you would like to have the issue further investigated please open a ticket with a moderator so that this question is reopened.

Answer (score 1):

That filefrag utility was a neat pointer. If it's not that then either your disks
are in terrible shape or something on your system is syncing so often that
you're not able cache enough of pages to achieve any sort of respectable throughput.

`hdparm -tT /dev/sda`  will give you a fair idea of what your disks can do.

Example

> /dev/sda:  Timing cached reads:   1370 MB in  2.00 seconds = 685.02
>   MB/sec  Timing buffered disk reads: 164 MB in  3.03 seconds =  54.18
>   MB/sec

If your buffered cache reads are no where close to this then there's your problem

Answer (score 0):

The files might be badly fragmented.  You can check that with the filefrag command.  Also there might be a problem with the disk.  Check /var/log/dmesg for errors relating to that disk.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I once had an Athlon 64 machine whose motherboard had some sort of problem with the Ubuntu drivers and gave a very slow transfer from/to the attached HDD's. I think it was a Gigabyte motherboard, and this was several years ago.

If I were you, I would search specifically for problems based on your motherboard, although another good thing to note would be whether the transfer was ever faster on your computer.